# How to set up Rails project to use Slim's pretty print option by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pretty-print, slim-lang

I want 'view source' in the browser to show the kind of HTML that would be created by running `slimrb` from the command line with the `-p` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure Slim to always pretty print your HTML output using the `:pretty` option, which defaults to `false`. Using Rails, the easiest place to set this would likely be in an environment file.

From the [docs](https://github.com/slim-template/slim#configuring-slim), they show this example adding this code to `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
# Indent html for pretty debugging and do not sort attributes
Slim::Engine.set_options pretty: true, sort_attrs: false
```

Note that using this option is slower (per the documentation), so you'll probably only want to do this in your development environment, as in the example.

Comment: Slower, I assume, by whatever time it takes to "calculate" the pretty-print, or is there some other delay at work?

Comment: That's my assumption as well. The speed difference might be negligible in practice, especially if you'd prefer having the unminified HTML output everywhere. It might be worth benchmarking if you're curious though.